# InvokeAndBlock causing EDT violation, everytime I used after showModeless dialog

Tags: java, codenameone

I am using InvokeAndBlock whenever any process based function performed. for example.

If I want to save something and it takes while to save the data then i used below code.

First show process dialog.

```
initProcessDialog();

progressDialog.showModeless(); // show process dialog


//Actual process

Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {

   public void run() {
      saveAll("SAVE_ALL",jobData);
      FileUtil.removeBackupFile(jobDataDetail.getJobTemplateFileName());
      progressDialog.dispose();
   }
});
```

also added InvokeAndBlock while any action performed which is time-consuming.

```
backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        initLoadingDialog();
        loadingDialog.showModeless();

        Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {  

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any correction require in process ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your calls to [invokeAndBlock](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#invokeAndBlock-java.lang.Runnable-) are mostly related to your own code its hard to tell what exactly you are doing.

The call to `dialog.dispose()` within `invokeAndBlock` is wrong. You need to call it after the `invokeAndBlock` which will work exactly the same without the EDT violation.

Codename One has one UI thread: [the EDT](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-1.html).

`invokeAndBlock` opens a separate thread where you aren't allowed to access any UI related API's.